# What is the best way of creating a getter / setter of a static field of a class so an instance of the class can call it

Tags: python, static-methods, getter-setter

I want to ask if this is the best way of writing a get/ set function for a class static field, that is a property of the class instance, not the class itself?

```
class MyClass:

    __static_field = "something"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def get_static_field():
        return MyClass.__static_field

    def get_static_field_with_instance(self):
        return self.__class__.__static_field

    def set_static_field_with_instance(self, new_value):
        self.__class__.__static_field = new_value
```

Here is some output:

```
print(MyClass.get_static_field())
>>> something
obj = MyClass()
print(obj.get_static_field_with_instance())
>>> something
obj.set_static_field_with_instance("smething new")
print(obj.get_static_field_with_instance())
>>> something new
```

Comment: Why would you use getters and setters with python? You can simply get or set value using ``MyClass.__static_field`` or ``MyClass.__static_field = 'new value'``. Or if you are changing the instance attribute use ``obj.__static_field``

Comment: @Liliane because I want to encapsulate my data

Comment: I'm not if encapsulation is needed in python, because python does not have private variables or private methods i.e. [we're all consenting adults here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html).

Comment: @Liliane - yes, but what if i have fields x and y representing coordinates. And what if I have decided from now on they are not x and y, but coords[0] and coords[1]. All those who use my api will have to rewrite their code from .x to .coords[1]. Using getters and setters I will have no such problem

Comment: I didn't think of that. But do expect that your users will not use the API in the way you have intended. They will probably use it in unexpected ways. For example, if you give a user getter and setter, they may ignore your recommendation to use it, and they will go straight to using class attribute. That way if you down the road change x to coords[0], then you will unintentionally nonetheless break the code of your users.